# How can I recursively insert the Fibonacci sequence into a binary tree

Tags: python, data-structures, fibonacci, recursive-datastructures

Hope someone can help, I'm not a programmer, but have been interested in exploring Fibonacci sequence and it's recursive tree...

I've created a Binary Tree class, along with an associated TreeNode class, and want to generate a binary tree of the recursive calls created by:

> f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) for a given value of n

I'd want to add it as an InsertFibonacci method of my Binary Tree class, replacing the standard Insert method:

```
def insertNode(self, root, inputData):
    if root == None:
        return self.addNode(inputData)
    else:
        if inputData <= root.nodeData:
            root.left = self.insertNode(root.left, inputData)
        else:
            root.right = self.insertNode(root.right, inputData)
        return root
```

Would I add somekind of decorator to the Fib function?

```
# Fib function
def f(n):

    def helper(n):
        left = f(n-1)
        right = f(n-2)
        return left,right

    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        left, right = helper(n)
        return left + right
```

Comment: Do you mean you want a data structure to represent the call graph for the recursive Fibonacci function? Then you shouldn't be using a binary *search* tree.

Comment: Hi Larsmans,

Yes, a data structure to represent the call graph. Doesn't the call graph represent a near complete strict binary tree structure though?

Comment: Yes, but the call graph is not a binary *search* tree, which is what `insertNode` seems to implement. A BST is a labeled binary tree with ordering constraints that the Fibonacci call graph does not exhibit.

Comment: Right, I understand the distinction. Many thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest solution I can think of:

```
class FibTree(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        if n < 2:
            self.value = n
        else:
            self.left = FibTree(n - 1)
            self.right = FibTree(n - 2)
            self.value = self.left.value + self.right.value
```

Comment: Many thanks Tzaman and Larsmans for your fast answers! I'll try out these solutions.

Comment: Many thanks @larsmans I've used your FibTree class and it works well. I've amended it, so each node includes a reference to it's parent:

    class FibTree(object):
 def __init__(self, n, parent):
  self.n = n
  self.parent = parent
  if n < 2:
   self.value = n
   self.left = None
   self.right = None
  else:
   self.left = FibTree(n - 1, self)
   self.right = FibTree(n - 2, self)
   self.value = self.left.value + self.right.value

I'd like to be able to ascertain for a given node whether it's a left or right sibling of it's parent. Is this possible, through the parent node link? Thanks Alex

Comment: how would it be possible to ascertain, given a node n, to test whether is Left or Right?

Comment: Just like I posted in my previous comment. `def is_left_child(self): return self is self.parent.left` (+ catch the exception raised when calling this on the root).

Comment: Thanks @larsmans. I slightly amended this for integration into the Class you intially setout: `def is_left_child(self, root):
  """ Returns true if Node is a left child """
  if root.parent:

The next thing I need to figure out is out to graphically visualise the tree hierarchy, showing parent-child relationships. Currently I've just done a breadth first traversal, but this only gives me children on each level and not relationships. Thanks Alex
   return root is root.parent.left
  else:
   return False`

Comment: Sorry about the above comment, my mark-up got somewhat screwed up and ran out of editing time!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
def insertFibonacci(self, n):
    current = self.addNode(n)
    if n > 1:
        current.left = self.insertFibonacci(n-1)
        current.right = self.insertFibonacci(n-2)
        # if you want the fibonacci numbers instead of the calls:
        # current.value = current.left.value + current.right.value
    return current
```

Assumes positive `n`. 
Should return the root of the fibonacci call tree.

Note that this won't exactly be the same kind of binary tree; it won't satisfy the ordering invariant that a binary search tree does. I'm assuming you just want to use your existing structure for convenience.

Comment: Many thanks @larsmans I've used your FibTree class and it works well. I've amended it, so each node includes a reference to it's parent: